# How to ignore any subsequent values from a ReplaySubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using an Angular library (https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) which helps with Google social signin

The library provides a ReplaySubject which emits values once the user has logged into Google and gives a user object containing data

For whatever reason, this ReplySubject omits duplicate objects at exactly the same time and even inspecting the microsecond time gives the same result so it is making it impossible for me to write code that ignores any 1 particular emit value

I have tried using .pipe(first()), .pipe(take(1)) and .pipe(last()) but this causes the ReplaySubject to not run at all

What other options do I have here to help me only take 1 particular Replay value and ignore the rest. I don't mind if I only take the 1st or the last as they are always identical with data

I am subscribing to the observable using:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

I have tried:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(distinct()).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I have also tried:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Also:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Also:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(first()).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Also:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(last()).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Also:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a === b)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Also:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a.id === b.id)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**Solved**

The component I was creating the subscription inside was being called twice. I think maybe the original authState subscription was staying active afterwards

Comment: can you post the code part where you subscribed to ReplaySubject

Comment: @jitender - That is now part of my OP

Comment: both of values might not be coming from same place there could be a case you are doing console.log while calling ```authService.signIn``` method as well can you post that code as well or while doing ```console.log``` just add message like ```console.log(val,'test 1')``` , ```console.log(val,'test 2')``` if you are doing multiple console.log

Comment: @jitender - I don't think that is the case. I have stripped down my project so that using angularx-social-login is only included in 1 place, which is where i'm doing my testing

Re - console.log. I have already added multiple parameters to console log and I can confirm they are coming from the same place every time

Comment: @jitender - I have solved the issue and the problem has been added to my OP. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this library but you could use [`distinctUntilChanged()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/distinctUntilChanged) and use a custom compare function (I'm expecting that the duplicate values are followed by each other).

There's eventually also [`distinct()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/distinct) operator that checks if the same value has been emitted so far by the chain.

Comment: Both distinct() and distinctUntilChanged() have not worked. this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(distinct()).subscribe(val => console.log(val)); still gives duplicates

Comment: @Ste You need to use a custom comparator function

Comment: I have added a distinctUntilChanged() custom comparator function now with the example in my OP but it doesn't give the result I need and still emits duplicates

Comment: `a === b` is comparing object identity so if `authState` emits some even objects this is useless. You need to pick some property that identifies each event.

Comment: I've added another example. The `id` property is equal in both objects as it's the Google user Id but no avail

Comment: or how about Pairwise and then filter out duplicates